# Subnumbering tables with kableExtra

Tags: latex, knitr, kableextra

I'm using Sweave (knitr) with `kableExtra` to generate tables like this:

[image]

Instead of Table 12, Table 13, I want to have *Table 12(a)*, *Table 12(b)*. How to do that?

One table is generated by such a code:

```
kable(dtabl, booktabs = TRUE, longtable = TRUE,
      align = rep("c", ncol(dtabl)), linesep = "",
      caption = paste0("Experimental Design of Qualification Data for level ", 
                       name, " of Group ", group),
      escape = FALSE) %>%
  add_header_above(extraheader) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header", "striped"))
```

I have a capricious internet connection, I will firstly post this message and then edit to add some details.

Comment: I'd guess whatever way you do this in LaTeX would have an equivalent in `knitr`, but I don't know how to do it in LaTeX.  Do you?

Comment: I do. I have found a solution. I'll post it when my connection will be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a LaTeX solution. Easy to adapt to Sweave (for example if you have an arbitrary number of tables).

```
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}(a)}

<<...>>=
...
@

\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}(b)}

\addtocounter{table}{-1}

<<...>>=
...
@
```

Comment: Nice.  And if you put `\label`s in the text, then `\ref`s to them show the table numbers as `12(a)`, `12(b)`, just the way you want.  And it works in R-Markdown too.  I'd just add one more `\renewcommand` at the end to restore the numbering to the usual format.